# Change the width of the region containing text on a GitHub Pages site

Tags: css, jekyll, github-pages

I currently have a GitHub Pages site which uses the `minimal` Jekyll template. There's only one problem: the part which contains text on the template is incredibly narrow, and I want to shrink the left and right margins of the page.

I tried the obvious: I changed the associated parameters with a CSS spreadsheet, but that ruined the entire formatting. I think this is probably a fairly common issue, so, any experience or sources? Thank you!